# Node-red switch node not working in IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

When using Node-Red from within IBM Bluemix I'm struggling to get the 'switch' node working in the current Node-Red version (v0.14.3). When I set a condition in the switch node then save it my changes don't persist and the condition(s) just revert to the default. e.g. I specify:
msg.payload <= 15
this gets changed (on save) to:
msg.payload == 15

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to get working. This has three nodes including a 'switch'. When I paste this into my Node-Red editor all conditions get changed to '=='. http://flows.nodered.org/flow/2832e7986c794f55708f

This works fine on v0.13.4 of Node-Red which I have running in a different instance.

Comment: This seams to be working OK for me. Might I suggest you raise this on the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red) where more in depth investigation can be done. Please include which browser you are using on what platform when you add the details

Comment: Rather than pasting in the example from an older/different version of nodered, have you tried creating that same flow by hand?

Answer (score 0):

This has now been raised as an [issue](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/928) on the Node-RED [github](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/) page.

It looks to be a rendering issue on Safari, the work around is to use Chrome or Firefox until a release with the fix is published